# Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I use NDK at first time and I have a problem, which I can't resolve about two days. I think the issue not unique, and the problem in some small details.

When I try to build example project I keep getting this error message when I try to compile using "ndk-build"

Android.mk

```
# File: Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

DEV_MODE := on

ifeq ($(DEV_MODE), on)

FLOWER_LIB_PATH := C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/proj/4ward/build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/bin/libflower.so

PHOTO_MAKER_LIB_PATH := C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\proj\PhotoMaker\build\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\src\PhotoMaker/libPhotoMaker.so

else # end of DEV_MODE = on

FLOWER_LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libflower.so

PHOTO_MAKER_LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libPhotoMaker.so

endif # DEV_MODE = off

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := flower-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FLOWER_LIB_PATH)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := photoMaker-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(PHOTO_MAKER_LIB_PATH)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


#######################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := wrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper_wrap.cxx
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -frtti
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := photoMaker-prebuilt flower-prebuilt
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += liblog
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

add.application.mk

```
# If APP_BUILD_SCRIPT is defined, check that the file exists.
# If undefined, look in $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Android.mk
#
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(strip $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
ifdef APP_BUILD_SCRIPT
    _build_script := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT)))
    ifndef _build_script
        $(call __ndk_info,Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
        $(call __ndk_error,Aborting...)
    endif
    APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(_build_script)
    $(call ndk_log,  Using build script $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
else
    ifeq (null,$(APP_PROJECT_PATH))
      $(call __ndk_info,NDK_PROJECT_PATH==null.  Please explicitly set APP_BUILD_SCRIPT.)
      $(call __ndk_error,Aborting.)
    endif

    _build_script := $(strip $(wildcard $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Android.mk))
```

Application.mk

```
 APP_PLATFORM := android-9
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86
    APP_STL := gnustl_shared
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -DWITH_LIVENESS -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
    #APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
```

[My logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scm0S.png)

Comment: Well does the file mentioned missing is indeed missing? did you check the path android.mk resides?

Comment: @pleft yes, sure. Path is correct

Comment: Have you tried using a path that doesn't contain any spaces?

Comment: @Michael Now it works. Thank you!!!