# Native library failed to load. Couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ndk-build

When I try to run my project on emulator x86-64 I get a crash. I have tried a lot of different solutions, but no one helped me to resolve my problem.

```
ndk {
            ldLibs "log"
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
```

> Engine Mobile: Native library failed to load:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/package-name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/package-name-1/lib/x86_64,
>   /data/app/package-name-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"

Here my Android.mk, add.application.mk and Application.mk files
[Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161873/android-ndk-your-app-build-script-points-to-an-unknown-file-android-mk-process)

Comment: Do you know what a native library is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes. And it library nice works on other devices. Problem only with x86-64.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you link statically against the STL (i.e. `gnustl_static`)?

Comment: @ПавелТихонов Have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

libgnustl_shared.so isn't in the Android system libraries. You'd have to include it in your apk libpath or link it statically like someone mentioned using gnustl_static. You could also use another c++ stl l  guess or if you have root just drop libgnustl_shared.so into /system/lib or /system/lib64